# Using $_GET in the same file of text field that I GET from

Tags: php, html, forms

Not sure if I titled it right, however my problem is stated below and I can't, for the life of me, figure it out.

> In the same file, write a form consisting of a single text field and a
>   submit button. The “action” attribute to the form should be the same
>   page that the form is on  (don’t hard code, use $_SERVER[‘PHP_SELF’]).
>   The form should send the contents of the text field via GET.
>   Upon submitting the form, you should be redirected to the same page,
>   but the URL should contain the string from the text field as a GET
>   request normally behaves.

```
<!-- I am supposed to pass the value of the text 
field over to the url according to the question -->
<form action="questionThree.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="text"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Have trouble getting the code to display properly. They're supposed to be in html tags, although it's a php file.

Comment: When you submit a form, the url should go to `questionthree.php?name=the_text_you_inputted`. You can then reference that with `$_GET['name']`. No idea what the actual PHP you have provided has anything to do with though.

Comment: @Albzi It is actually from a set of questions where you're supposed to use the same file for all questions, whether they're related or not.

Comment: So it is not relevant to this specific question being asked?

Comment: The whole php section in the original post isn't relevant.

Comment: Ok I'm going to edit your post just for clarity :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im baffled as to why you're passing it somewhere else however..

I think I have made sense from what you're asking so here goes...

On the submit input field add `name="send"`

then the HTML and PHP (for the same page) would be:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="send">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['send']))
{
    $sentence = strtolower("My name is Justin and I am learning PHP programming and C++ programming");

    function countWords($sentence)
    {
        //Using 'explode' to split words, thereby creating an array of these words
        $wordsArr = explode(' ', $sentence);
        $vals = array_count_values($wordsArr);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($vals);
        echo "</pre>";
        foreach ($vals as $key => $value)
        {
            echo "<b>" . $key . "</b> occurs " . $value . " times in this sentence <br/>";
        }
    }
    countWords($sentence);
}
?>
```

Though I still see no purpose of the input text field?

Comment: only thing I can think of is that `$sentence` is maybe meant to be `$_GET['send']` but i'm not too sure.

Comment: I did think that also but never the less, if the Op clarifies this i'll edit it accordingly.

Comment: @Option Apologies for the unclear post. I had replied to Albzi in the original comment section. The $sentence is from another question. I am just supposed to add the other non-related code to the same file anyway.

Comment: No problem at all.